Derived tables not getting the same results with Join
Two queries almost identical give different results see below:
Why is this query getting the results I want:
select
z.numb, x.numb_type, z.type, z.acct, x.amt, z.amt
from
(
select
a1.numb numb, a1.numb_typ numb_typ, sum(a1.amt) amt
from tbl_1 a1
where 1=1
and a1.type = 'white'

-- When I put the below criteria in the query I get the expected 
-- results.  But of course with only a limited amount of data when I 
-- want to do this
-- against the whole dataset

and a1.numb = '1'
and a1.numb_type in ('G1','G15')
group by a1.col_1, a1.col_2
) 
z
left join
(
select
a.numb numb, a.numb_type, ha.acct acct, sum(a1.amt) amt
from tbl_1 a, ha.tbl_2
where a.acct = ha.acct
and a.type = 'white'
and a.numb = '1'
group by a.col_1, ha.col_2
) x
on (substr(x.col_2,2,2) = substr(z.acct,2,2) and x.numb = z.numb)
;


Results, notice the bottom row, with the null results based on the join:
|1|G1 |  white | 990 | 20 | 15 
|1|G1 |  white |990 | 30 | 30 
|1|G15 | null | null |  null | 30  

But this query against the same data does not return any rows from the left side that are not in the right side?
select
z.numb, x.numb_type, z.type, z.acct, x.amt, z.amt
from
(
select
a1.numb numb, a1.numb_typ numb_typ, sum(a1.amt) amt
from tbl_1 a1
where 1=1
and a1.type = 'white'
group by a1.col_1, a1.col_2
) 
z
left join
(
select
a.numb numb, a.numb_type, ha.acct acct, sum(a1.amt) amt
from tbl_1 a, ha.tbl_2
where a.acct = ha.acct
and a.type = 'white'
group by a.col_1, ha.col_2
) x
on (substr(x.col_2,2,2) = substr(z.acct,2,2) and x.numb = z.numb)
;


Results, notice all I've done is remove the filter, but same tables, now no null results from the join:
  |1|G1 |  white | 990 | 20 | 15 
  |1|G1 |  white |990 | 30 | 30 
  |2|G2 | white | 990 | 15 | 100
  |3|H1 | white | 991 | 35 | 55
  |4|A2 | white | 992 | 35 | 55
 


Why do you expect the same result?  You filter by entity in the 1st query but not in the 2nd.

I don’t see the 10050 number

I think I understand now what you are asking. You will have to provide minimal sample data (as text) that is enough to demonstrate the problem.

I edited your post to move your explanation inside the code. Hopefully it's OK with you.

Edited, hopefully I did that right to minimize the text.

I meant we need source data  (your table) that will produce the described results when using your queries.
